# Downloading a compressed file under Perl

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

I'm trying to download a .tar.gz file (which I will then uncompress.... but that's for later.)

I've hunted through CPAN, Stackoverflow, and Perl Monks, and the following snippit downloads the file & stores it on disk (and doesn't delete it until you hit enter for the `<>`.)

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use File::Temp;

# Create temporary file, and delete on script-exit
my $tmp = File::Temp->new( TEMPLATE => 'hathiXXXX', SUFFIX=>'.tar.gz', UNLINK=>1 );

my $uri = 'http://lucas.ucs.ed.ac.uk/test/hathi_full_20150701.txt.gz';
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();

# Set the mime-type for a .tar.gz file
$ua->default_header('Accept' => 'application/x-gzip');

# ':content_file' => $tmp->filename is LWP magic to write to a file
my $res = $ua->get($uri, ':content_file' => $tmp->filename);
print $tmp->filename . "\n";

# Once you hit enter, the temporary file is deleted
<>;
```

Using `wget` I get a file I can uncompress.
The above script saves a file..... which I can't open.

Both return files that are the same size, have the same `md5sum` checksum, and appear to have the same first & last 64 bytes.....

What have I missed? How do I get this dang file?

Thanks...

(Perl:5.18.2; LWP::UserAgent:6.05; File::Temp:0.23)

Comment: Why can't you open it? What error do you get?

Comment: tar: This does not look like a tar archive
    tar: Skipping to next header
    tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: OK. What flags are you passing to tar? Sounds like you need to add a `z`. E.g. `tar xvfz <filename>` and then it'll gunzip it first. If it's the same md5sum, then it's the same content, so you don't have to worry about encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

****GGNNNNN*****

**TIP** - read the *ACTUAL* question!!!

The file being downloaded has the suffix `.txt.gz` - it is NOT a `tar` file. Using GUI tools to open it will work, because they don't make *stupid assumptions* and seamlessly select the correct tool for the job.

Files ending in `txt.gz` need to be unpacked with `gunzip`, not `tar`

Answer (score 1):

The file you're downloading is a txt.gz file, and appears to contain tab separated data, not a tar format file.